# Are there any other options to avoid sql injection besides prepared statements in php/mysql web applications?

Tags: php, mysql

I know that when we talk about sql injection in php/mysql prepared stamtements is the way to go and even so we are never sure if that is enough, but i'd like to know if there are any other efficient workarounds to prevent sql injection.

Also I have this little function to parse strings in an attempt to avoid the basic sql injection attacks.

```
function cleanString($str) {
$strEncoding = mb_detect_encoding($str) != 'UTF-8' ? 'ISO-8859-15' : 'UTF-8';
$str = trim($str);
$str = preg_replace('/(\s|\%20){2,}/', ' ', $str);// Elimino espacios
$str = preg_replace('/\t|\%09|\%0b|\%0B/', ' ', $str);// Elimino tabulaciones
$str = preg_replace('/\n|\r|\%0a|\%0A|\%0d|\%0D/', '', $str);// Elimino entradas de nueva línea

// Caracteres especiales más importantes ", &, ', (, ), -, ;, <, =, >, `, ~

$str = preg_replace('/\(|\)|\-{2}|;|`|~/', '', $str);// Elimino algunos caracteres especiales
// Elimino cadenas y secuencia de bytes sospechosas
$str = preg_replace('/((0x2)(2|6|7|8|9|d|D))|((0x3)(b|B|c|C|d|D|e|E))|0x60|0x7e|0x7E/', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/\%22|\%26|\%27|\%28|\%29|\%2d|\%2D|\%3b|\%3B|\%3c|\%3C|\%3d|\%3D|\%3e|\%3E|\%60|\%7e|\%7E/', '', $str);

return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, $strEncoding);
}
```

The function affects strings because it replaces some basic characters((, ), ;) that users might enter in their inputs, but i figure it would work pretty much the same even if i allow those characters.

Comment: is it not preferable to use the `mysql_real_escape_string` function to escape strings for use in mysql statements?

Comment: Don't accept user input. Then they can never inject anything. ;)

Comment: Please use prepared statements or a database library that takes care of quoting for you rather than writing your own code. It is enough.

Comment: PDO & prepared statements will be much more reliable and much simpler than anything you can come up with. Just put in the effort and learn how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter input with mysql_real_escape(), and htmlspecialchars(), to stop injections and stop XSS(?). Binding parameters and preparing queries is better though.